# how to remove validation on success for hidden fields using jquery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to hide the validation error on success in hidden field ,

```
<form id="some-id">
    <input name="from" class="form-control" id="from type="text">
    <input type="hidden" class="id-from" name="idfrom">
</form>
```

```js
$('#some-id).validate({    
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        idfrom: "required",
    },
});
```

On change of input class the hidden value will set, so I need the hidden field as required. It works fine but the error message is not hiding on success and moving to next field. It's hiding only when submitting the `form`. I have tried this:

```
unhighlight: function (element) {
    $(element).removeClass('error')
}
```

However it removes only for the focused field, not hidden fields.

Answer (score 1):

You have not explained the purpose of this hidden field or why it needs to be validated.  If it automatically updates itself based on a text field, why not simply validate the original text field instead?

**Why it happens:**

By default, the validation test is triggered by `blur` & `keyup` events on the input elements, and on the `click` event of the submit button.  Since you have an invisible hidden element that the user cannot see or interact with, there are no `blur` or `keyup` events on it.  This leaves only the click of the submit that can trigger a validation test on this element.

**How to fix it:**

You'll need to write an event handler that captures the `blur` and `keyup` events of the text input element, and programmatically trigger a validation test using the `.valid()` method on the hidden element.

```
$('[name="from"]').on('keyup blur', function() {
    $('[name="idfrom"]').valid();  // force validation test
});
```